# how can receive the value of a promise without executing the rest of the code? I am getting [objetc,object]

Tags: javascript

this function should return "HomeStack"

```
const getSessionPrevious = async () => {
try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token"); //value default is "#$#"%2356"
    if (value !== null) {
    return "HomeStack";
    } else {
    return "LoginStack";
    }
 } catch (error) {
    return "LoginStack";
 }
};

console.log(getSessionPrevious() ); //I need get the value of the function in this line
.
.
.
rest of my code
```

when I do:

```
console.log(getSessionPrevious );
```

returns:

```
      Promise {
        "_40": 0,
        "_55": null,
        "_65": 0,
        "_72": null,
      }
```

how can get the result of this promise?

Comment: You are not awaiting for your `getSessionPrevious ` function to be resolve. You need an `await`keyword. : `console.log(await getSessionPrevious );`

Comment: it causes error

Comment: Can you describe what is the error ?

Comment: @Nicolas  i.imgur.com/4h1pHxq.jpg

Comment: try assigning the value to a variable first,

Comment: also, you need to call the actual function, you are declaring it but never calling it

Comment: @Nicolas console.log(await getSessionPrevious() ); same error

Comment: well i don't know then. Good luck with that

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1)  will help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "without executing the rest of the code"?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add parenthesis to actually call the function. Then you need to call the function using `await` to actually wait for the return value. Since you can only use `await` in an `async` function, declare one for that purpose.

```
async function Demo()
{
    console.log(await getSessionPrevious()); 
}

Demo();

// Code here will be executed before Demo() is actually executed because we are not awaiting it.
```

Note that adding asynchronous code (like async/await or using plain promises) is contagious. If you want to work with the results, you have to support the async nature of the call all up the callstack. This is very well explained in these topics:

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you are trying to get an asynchronous value from the top-level, you have to use `then`, `catch`:

```js
getSessionPrevious().then(value => {
  console.log("Previous session", value);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log("Error getting previous session", error);
});
```

Or you can also use an encapsulated anonymous asynchronous function:

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const value = await getSessionPrevious();
    console.log("Previous session", value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error getting previous session", error);
  }
})();
```